# How to print text from a file in a knitr doc?

Tags: knitr

I wish to read in a text file and print it verbatim in a knitr doc.  I got some code to read a text file into a string:

```
filename = 'foo.txt'
text = readChar(filename, file.info(filename)$size)
```

However, my every attempt to print out the text results in ugly craziness.  Using print() does not wrap the lines.  It leaves "## [1]" all over the output. Using results='asis' doesn't do what I want.  Trying \verbatim and \spverbatim doesn't do the right thing.

What is the easy way out here?

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work with

```
\begin{spverbatim}
\Sexpr{text}
\end{spverbatim}
```

not in a knitr block.